# Error 310 - when I try to access the Steam market

Tags: steam-community-market

Whenever I try to access the Steam Community Market, it just shows

> Error -310 (unknown)

Googling got me nowhere. Has anyone heard of this error/know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam's errors usually correspond to [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). While there are some that may indicate a problem on your end (like a connection failure or expired authentication) this one is a bit special (it's not usually listed with the "standard" HTTP codes) and means "too many redirects". It hints at a server-side problem, for example a programming mistake.

Comment: I don't know why Valve prefixes the code with a minus, but even more annoyingly it's always shown as "unknown".

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post but just in case someone finds this thread with the same question:

I've had this happen on two different occasions while browsing the Steam Store on my desktop application and both times I was able to get around it by searching for the game with the Steam Store on my web browser and after you click play/buy now click the option "Yes, I have steam installed" and it opens steam and downloads just fine.